# google map get boundries of provinces

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon

Is there any way to get coordinates (lat and long) of province boundaries which are presented as dashed line on the map? I want to save them and use them to show polygon of each province of my country (Iran).

tnx a million

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_query_sidebarF_local.html?country=Iran)?  (uses publicly available data; Natural Earth Data in FusionTables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days of searching I found a great way:

1- use [this link](https://www.openstreetmap.org) and search for the province or state which you are looking for, clicking on it would give you and id.

2- copy and paste the id in [this link](http://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/) and enjoy your wkt!